# Is _.initial more verbose than it needs to be in Underscore.js?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

This is `underscore.js`'s code for `_.initial`:

```
  // Returns everything but the last entry of the array. Especially useful on
  // the arguments object. Passing **n** will return all the values in
  // the array, excluding the last N.
  _.initial = function(array, n, guard) {
    return slice.call(array, 0, Math.max(0, array.length - (n == null || guard ? 1 : n)));
  };
```

It seems to me that the following would be less verbose and equivalent:

```
  _.initial = function(array, n, guard) {
    return slice.call(array, 0, Math.min(0, -(n == null || guard ? 1 : n)));
  };
```

Asking about such a detail is not out of place because `underscore.js` attempts to save as many bytes as possible. Take, for instance, this comment:

```
  // Save bytes in the minified (but not gzipped) version:
  var ArrayProto = Array.prototype, ObjProto = Object.prototype, FuncProto = Function.prototype;
```

Is there a reason for the more verbose code?

Answer (score 0):

I now see that it differs at the extreme case where `n` is `0`. It seemed like a compelling issue before that, though. It would be useless to write the extreme case: `_.initial(collection, 0)` since it would be equivalent to `collection` (give or take being a real array); however, it is quite possible that some code that needs to vary `n` might use the extreme case with `n = 0`.